# Dihedral in a regular spherical polygon

Tags: solid-geometry, spherical-trigonometry

Planes rotate around a central symmetry axis  pass through a sphere centre to intersect on the sphere forming  a regular spherical polygon of $n$ sides.

A small circle forms as base of cone semi-vertical angle $\alpha$ circumscribing the vertices of the polygon.

If $\delta$  is the dihedral  angle between successive planes then show that
$$ \tan \dfrac {\delta}{2} =\tan \dfrac {\pi}{n} \;\cos \alpha $$

Special case in Euclidean geometry when $\alpha\rightarrow 0$ sum of external angles of a regular polygon:
$$ n \delta = {2\pi}. $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The planes carve a regular spherical polygon in the surface of the (unit) sphere, such that the dihedral angles $\delta$ between the planes match the exterior angles of the polygon. The semi-vertical angle $\alpha$ of the cone gives the (spherical) circumradius of the polygon.

[image]

If $P$ is the center of the polygon, $Q$ one of its vertices, and $A$ the midpoint of a side adjacent to $Q$, then $\triangle PQA$ is a spherical right triangle with hypotenuse $\alpha$ and acute angles $\pi/n$ and $(\pi-\delta)/2$.

By the [Spherical Law of Cosines for Angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines), we have

$$\begin{align}
\cos A &= -\cos P \cos Q + \sin P \sin Q \cos\alpha \\[4pt]
0  &= -\cos\frac{\pi}{n}\sin\frac\delta2+\sin\frac{\pi}{n}\cos\frac\delta2\cos\alpha \\[4pt]
\tan\frac{\delta}{2} &= \tan\frac{\pi}{n}\;\cos\alpha
\end{align}$$
as desired. $\square$